# why my percentage doesnt count 100% mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-select-db

i have a fiddle just like this

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
    id_order VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    createdAt datetime NOT NULL,
    sale DECIMAL(14,2) NOT NULL,
    id_location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    createdby varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    order_status_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_order,createdAt)
);

INSERT INTO sales(id_order,createdAt,sale, id_location, createdby, order_status_id)
VALUES(1,'2016-02-02',100, 1, 123, 5),
      (2,'2017-03-02',150, 2, 233, 6),
      (3,'2018-02-02',200, 3, 234, 6),
      (4,'2016-03-03',150, 1, 123, 7),
      (5,'2017-03-04',100, 2, 2334, 7),
      (6,'2018-03-05',200,3, 234, 7),
       (7,'2016-03-10',200, 1, 233, 7),
      (8,'2017-02-01',150, 2, 124, 8),
      (9,'2018-02-04',250, 3, 233, 8),
      (10,'2018-02-05',300, 2, 124, 6);

 CREATE TABLE location(
 id_location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 location_city varchar(50) NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO location(id_location, location_city)
 VALUES(1, 'Jakarta'),
 (2, 'Depok'),
 (3, 'Bekasi');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b22217bc34e3fb40c41cbaf065ca7659

then i applied this syntax into my real database like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(customer_regency, 'Total') AS `Kabupaten/Kota`, 
       SUM(quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
       round(SUM(quantity) / any_value(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty(%)`, 
       COUNT(order_buyer_id) AS `Jumlah Order`,
       round(COUNT(order_buyer_id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order(%)`
FROM order_match

/* 1 */ INNER JOIN air_way_bills 
/* 1 */ ON order_match.code_order = air_way_bills.code_order
/* 2 */ INNER JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM order_match s1
               WHERE s1.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING SUM(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-01-02' AND '2020-02-03')
                  AND SUM(s1.createdAt <= '2020-02-03') > 1 ) clients 
/* 2 */ ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(quantity) totalsum, 
              COUNT(order_buyer_id) totalcount 
       FROM order_match
/* 3 */  INNER JOIN ( SELECT s2.createdby
                      FROM order_match s2
                      WHERE s2.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
                      GROUP BY s2.createdby
                      HAVING SUM(s2.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-01-02' AND '2020-02-03')
                         AND SUM(s2.createdAt <= '2020-02-03') > 1 ) clients 
/* 3 */ ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
       WHERE order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)) totals
WHERE order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP;
```

im lil bit confused in my real database why the output of total percentage counted 99,6 % (it's should be 100% if we talk about **TOTAL**)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/62576)

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, I see: `count(id_order) (%)` results in `100`, and the number `99` or `99.6` does not appear at all.  Is that the right fiddle?

Comment: yes sir, result 100 on the fiddle was right, but on my real data in my real mysql, it's 99 percent not 100 percent dont know exactly was going wrong @HoldOffHunger

Comment: still didnt understand what should i do to fix this case sir @KenWhite